# how to generate excell sheet using html nested tables using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to genrate a excel sheet with follwing data which is html table format and inside the table another table also placed but am getting excel sheet with repeated cells how can i resolve this? 
please help me if you have any idea about this

```js
        $(document).ready(function(){
    

        $("#btn").click(function(){
        $("#dvData").table2excel({
        exclude:".noExl",
        name:"my Bio",
        filename:"Bio data"
        });

          });
         });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<doctype html>
     <html>
      <head>
     <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/unconditional/jquery-table2excel/master/src/jquery.table2excel.js"></script>
          <script>

       </script>
       </head>
   
       <body>
       <table id="dvData" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
       <thead>
         <tr>
                <th>dec</th>
                <th>Jan</th>
                <th>Feb</th>
                <th>Mar</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
         [1] <tbody>
            
            <tr> 
            <td>karthik</td>
            <td>neta</td>
            <td>tarun</td>
            <td>
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr><td>hi</td></tr>
            <tr><td>hi</td></tr>
            <tr><td>hi</td></tr>
            </table>
            </td></tr>
                        <tr><td>karthik</td><td>neta</td><td>tarun</td><td>srepath</td></tr>

            <tr><td>karthik</td><td>neta</td><td>tarun</td><td>srepath</td></tr>

            <tr><td>karthik</td><td>neta</td><td>tarun</td><td>srepath</td></tr>

            <tr><td>karthik</td><td>neta</td><td>tarun</td><td>srepath</td></tr>
            <tr><td>karthik</td><td>neta</td><td>tarun</td><td>srepath</td></tr>
            <tr><td>karthik</td><td>neta</td><td>tarun</td><td>srepath</td></tr>


            <tr><td>karthik</td><td>neta</td><td>tarun</td><td>srepath</td></tr>

            <tr><td>karthik</td><td>neta</td><td>tarun</td><td>srepath</td></tr>

            
        </tbody>
       
    </table>
    <button id="btn" class="btn btn-success">excelll</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

the below image is excell sheet. From that excel you observe  that the table data which is in the nested table is coming two tims in excell sheet. 
for example hi message is in nested table it is appearing 6 times.

And i want excell sheet like this which is attached below
[image]

Comment: this is actually what i get if i just run your code

Comment: iam getting output like below attached image